# LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain causes AssemblyResolve to not fire

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, assemblyresolve

I have some issues as soon as `LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain`is enabled.
Somehow, it doesn't fire AssemblyResolve event anymore when an assembly is not found in some specific scenarios.

I narrowed it down to a repro case with 2 projects.
You can download full solution here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/24787-appdomainresolvetest.zip

Let's say I have a top level program:

```
class AppProgram
{
    // Comment this and both Resolve1 and Resolve2 will happen
    // If enabled, Resolve2 doesn't happen
    [LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain)]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var applicationPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        var appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = Directory.GetParent(applicationPath).FullName };
        var otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("other domain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, appDomainSetup);
        otherDomain.DoCallBack(TestCallback);
    }

    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Resolve1 {args.Name}");
        return null;
    }

    private static void TestCallback()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        var remoteAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("ConsoleApplication1");
        remoteAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[0] });
    }
}
```

Then, assembly ConsoleApplication1 has the following code:

(Note that Newtonsoft.Json is referenced (w/ NuGet) but has Copy Local set to false, which result in an intentional assembly resolve and FileNotFoundException)

```
class ConsoleProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
        try
        {
            Test();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true);
    }


    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Resolve2 {args.Name}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

What happens is that, if `LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain` attribute is not set on Main, both Resolve1 (from top-level program) and Resolve2 (from library) are called.
However, as soon as `LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain` is set, only Resolve1 is called.

In my actual application, MultiDomain is critical to avoid JIT and initialize assemblies again (reduce second startup time from 5 second to almost nothing).
As a result, I would like to understand the root cause of this bug and hopefully find a work around.

Edit: even when trying to harddcode my resolve during Resolve1, it seems like it can't cache assemblies (loading is slow).
Maybe MultiDomain only works for assemblies in `ApplicationBase`?
In that case, I suppose I will have to use the PrivateBinPath to optimize JIT.
Would still like to know if the AssemblyResolve bug can be solved because there is still a few extra assemblies loaded from external path which I don't care if they are not JIT.

Comment: Note: submitted on Microsoft Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/214568/when-using-loaderoptimizationmultidomain-assemblyr.html